# PostgreSQL: Executing DDL on every schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I've a multi-tenant DB setup, and need to add some columns.  I'm using schemas (and search_path) to partition my users, so I'm looking for a ubiquitous way to apply a DDL-schema change to all my databases.  Initially, I'd thought I might be able to do it as a single query (cursor on pg_catalog), but thinking a command-line invocation of `psql -f` might be the preferred way.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: `Postgres` instead of `PostgreSQL` is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would prefer the latter solution.  You can collect the schema names into a file (one schema per line) in `psql`:

```
\o change_schema.sql
\t on

SELECT n.nspname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema';

-- reset the output
\o
\t off
```

Then you can easily do the following:

Have a DDL changing script (for example, `change_schema.sql`), without reference to the including schema

```
SET search_path TO :schema;

BEGIN;
...
...
ALTER TABLE orders
ADD COLUMN last_modified timestamp;
...
...
COMMIT;
```

Then you can turn every line of the schema list into a line like

```
psql -h dbhost -d targetdb -f change_schema.sql -v schema=<schema_name>
```

with a simple `sed` command, for example - then you just have to run these commands.   Of course, you can turn it into a proper shell script if you like.

Comment: This is how I'd do it too, though I'd use the shell to *loop over* the schema list, rather than sed'ing it, so I had better error handling. Just for completeness, the other approach would be to write it as a PL/PgSQL procedure that used `EXECUTE` to run the statements as dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 11):

Just for completeness, another approach is to loop over all schemas and run the change with dynamic SQL in PL/PgSQL, eg:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    schemaname name;
BEGIN
   FOR schemaname IN SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%' AND nspname <> 'information_schema' LOOP
       EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.my_table ADD COLUMN blah blah;', schemaname);
   END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```